# How to create controls dynamically in JFace Wizard

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a jFace wizard, I am using this to create a new project type eclipse plugin. As you can see from image below, I have one treeviewer on left side, and a SWT group on right side. What I want is when ever user selects one of the item from treeviewer, I should be able to create dynamic controls on right side SWT Group. Say user selects Test One, one right side I should be able to create few controls like label, text and few radio buttons on right side, similarly if user selects Test Two I should be able to create dynamic controls on right side.
[image]

Currently I tried below code:

```
tree.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
     @Override
 public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
     for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {

     String tempStr = selection[i].toString();
     tempStr = tempStr.replaceAll("TreeItem \\{", "");
     String finalStr = tempStr.replaceAll("\\}", "");

         if (finalStr.equals("Test One")) {
             Button btn = new Button(g2, SWT.NONE); //g2 is right side group

             btn.setText("Blaaaa");

             btn.setVisible(true);
             container.redraw();
         }

}
```

But when I run, I see no changes on right group. Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong? Any pointers would be very appreciated, since I am new to Eclipse development and SWT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably didn't set a layout on the `g2` group. This is the common cause for controls not showing up. You can also try using `g2.layout()` to ensure that the new controls are correctly laid out after you create them.

Additionally you could look at using a [`StackLayout`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FStackLayout.html) so that once you create a set of controls you can just hide them all at once instead of destroying when the selection changes. This is often useful so that if the user comes back to a previous selection, they will find the data they entered in the same state when they switched the selection. [Here is an example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet249.java).